# The tasks argument included a null value

Tags: c#, .net, task

I'm using mvc 5 and follow [this sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate an array Task.

I'm sure database contains 1 row at least with the query. I think I'm getting the problem with Task, because it threw me error message

> The tasks argument included a null value.

when I tried:

```
// I'm sure `cg` was not null and `type` was not empty
var cg = new List<string>();
var type = "";

var db = new MyDbContext();
var list = new List<TopicViewModels>();

if (cg != null && cg.Count > 0)
{
   var tasks = new Task<List<TopicViewModels>>[13];
   byte i = 0;

   while (i < cg.Count)
   {
      string _cg = cg[i];

      tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () => 
      {
         return await db.Topics.Where(m => m.Type == type && m.Category == _cg)
            .ToListAsync();
      });

      i++;
   }

   var continuation = Task.WhenAll(tasks); //the tasks argument included a null value

   // never go to this loop...
   foreach (var topics in continuation.Result)
   {
      topics.ForEach(x => list.Add(x));
   }
}
```

I've set breakpoint to check array `tasks`, `tasks[0]` was not null. It's appened correctly.

Can you explain me why?

**UPDATE:** (based on @YacoubMassad comment)

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks); //same error here...

//never go to this loop, too...
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
   //
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** (based on @DavidPine answer)

```
if (cg != null && cg.Count > 0)
{
   var tasks = new List<Task<List<TopicViewModels>>>();
   cg.ForEach(x =>
   {
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
      {
         return await db.Topics.Where(m => m.Type == type && m.Category == x)
            .ToListAsync();
      }));
   });

   foreach (var topics in await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()))
   {
      topics.ForEach(x => list.Add(x));
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the method where this code exists `async`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad yup. It's in `public async Task<ActionResult> Topics(){}`

Comment: Try to change `var continuation = Task.WhenAll(tasks);` to `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` and then loop through the `tasks` array

Comment: I think that one problem is that `cg.Count` could be less than 13

Comment: @YacoubMassad I just try again and update my question. Please check

Comment: @YacoubMassad If the problem is `cg.Count`, some exception maybe: `index was outside the bounds of the array`

Comment: if(cg.Count < 13) then the `tasks` will contain null values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

**1.** When working with `Task` or `Task<T>` always use `async / await` if it is available, i.e.; you're working with .NET 4.5.

**2.** When you invoke `Task.WhenAll(tasks)`, it is possible that there is a task in the array that is null.  You need to check that for that and handle it correctly.

**3.** You need to await the when all to ensure the work is done, `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

```
var cg = new List<string>();
var type = "";

var db = new MyDbContext();
var list = new List<TopicViewModels>();

if (cg != null && cg.Count > 0)
{
   var tasks = new Task<List<TopicViewModels>>[13];
   byte i = 0;

   while (i < cg.Count)
   {
      string _cg = cg[i];

      tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () => 
      {
         // Isn't it possible that the where clause filters out and returns null?
         return await db.Topics
                        .Where(m => m.Type == type && m.Category == _cg)
                        .ToListAsync();
      });

      i++;
   }

   // Use await keyword to ensure that work is done
   var continuation = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Where(t => t != null).ToArray());

   // never go to this loop...
   foreach (var topics in continuation.Result)
   {
      topics.ForEach(x => list.Add(x));
   }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: It would be better if you store the tasks in a list instead of an array. This way you wouldn't have a problem even if you have more than 13 tasks.

Comment: Another big problem with your code. `db` is not thread safe and you are calling it from many threads at once.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems in your code.

First of all, you using naturally asynchronous methods that query a database, you don't need to execute then on a threadpool thread, that's redundant, especially in ASP.NET which already uses thread pool threads to serve requests.

Second of all, you're not awaiting on the task returned by `Task.WhenAll`, you're synchronously blocking when iterating in the `foreach` loop using `Task.Result`.

You're code should be:

```
var queryTasks = cg.Select(cg => db.Topics.Where(m => m.Type == type && m.Category == cg).ToListAsync());
return await Task.WhenAll(queryTasks);
```

Do note that that EF `DbContext` is not thread-safe, and doesn't allow concurrent operations to be executed on it. If that is the case here, you'll need to `await` each query independently.